# Gather and display "viewed" statistics about Documentation topics

Tags: feature-request, documentation

By looking at the activity of creation and deletion of topics we know how popular they are for creators. But it would also be nice to see how popular they are for visitors. Therefore, collect and display "viewed" statistics as in the Q&A part.